# How can I get only the line for the first occurrence of a word after a specific line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the text file I'm working on there are multiple lines containing the word "TOP", however, I want to get only the first occurrence coming after lines containing the word "IPT".
The second question I want to ask if it would be a better idea to work with Pandas library since it is csv (comma separated values) file.

Here's my code, but it gets all of the lines containing the word "TOP":

```
temp = { } # Keys will be the line number, and values will be the lines that contains "IPT" with newline character removed
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    fileNum = 0
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        fileNum +=1
        if line[12:17] == "IPT":
            temp[fileNum] = line.replace('\n', '')
            continue
            if line[12:15] == "TOP":
                print(line)
```

Example of my text file:

```
....
....
...SAT...
...
...TOP # I don't want to get this line
...
...
**...IPT...
...
...
...TOP... # I want to get this line**
...
...
...SAT...
...
...TOP... # I don't want to get this line.
**...IPT...
...TOP... # I want to get this line.**
```

Comment: Are the ellipsis (...) in your example output just there to replace other data or the actual contents of the file?

Comment: @IainShelvington They are there to replace other irrelevant data. "TOP" words sit at line[12:15] substring in a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code just add variable, marking, whether `IPT` was already found or not.

```py
temp = { } # Keys will be the line number, and values will be the lines that contains "IPT" with newline character removed
found_ipt=False
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    fileNum = 0
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        fileNum +=1
        if line[12:17] == "IPT":
            temp[fileNum] = line.replace('\n', '')
            found_ipt=True
        elif (line[12:15] == "TOP") & found_ipt:
             print(line)
             found_ipt=False
```

Comment: This worked pretty well, though I had to block out the last if block. Can you please tell me how continue statement effects the code's control flow?

Comment: Yes, I think moving it to ```pandas``` would make this kind of operations easier.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm you can drop ```continue``` indeed. You might use ```pass``` instead, or just don't use any of those...

Comment: I tweaked the answer a bit - since these 2 literals aren't supposed to occur in one line - you need to move the last if one level up. Then ```continue``` actually makes sense...

Comment: Yes, it is true that "TOP" and "IPT" do not occur in one line, however, I still think that 'continue' statement is unnecessary, since the 'elif' statement will not run unless 'found_ipt' variables is 'True', which depends on the execution of the 'if line[12:17] == "IPT":' statement. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

You have two actions to write :

1. When you haven't seen `IPT` and `IPT` is in the line : save the line and start looking for `TOP`
2. When you see `TOP` and `IPT` has been seen : print the line and stop looking for `TOP`

Also, just look for basic string inclusion `"TOP" in line` rather than looking at a specific index, you don't need to be so specific here

```
temp = {}
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    search_mode = False
    for idx, line in enumerate(myfile):       # enumerate() return tuple : index + content  
        if not search_mode and "IPT" in line: # action 1
            temp[idx] = line.rstrip()
            search_mode = True
        elif search_mode and "TOP" in line:   # action 2
            print(line)
            search_mode = False
```

Gives :

```
print(json.dumps(temp, indent=4))
# >>>
...TOP... # I want get this line**

...TOP... # I want get this line.**
{
    "7": "**...IPT...",
    "16": "**...IPT..."
}
```

Pandas Dataframe are used for collection of labeled datas (imagine a CSV content) that's not what you have here

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of whether you have found IPT yet in a variable "found".  Then only look for TOP if found == True.  The first time you find TOP after found == True is what you are looking for and you can stop looking.

```
temp = { } # Keys will be the line number, and values will be the lines that contains "IPT" with newline character removed
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    fileNum = 0
    found = False
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        fileNum +=1
        if line[12:17] == "IPT":
            temp[fileNum] = line.replace('\n', '')
            found = True
        if found == True && line[12:15] == "TOP":
            print(line)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```py
temp = { } # Keys will be the line number, and values will be the lines that contains "IPT" with newline character removed
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as myfile:
    # This variable shows if a "IPT" has been found
    string_found = False
    #  enumerate returns a generator of tuples, the first value of the tuple is the index (starting at 0), the second the line content
    for line_num, line in enumerate(myfile.readlines()):
        # if the string "IPT" is in our line and we haven't already found a previous IPT, we set string_found to True to signal that we can now get the next "TOP"
        if "IPT" in line and not string_found:
            string_found = True
        # If there is a "TOP" in our line and we have already found an IPT previously, save the line
        elif "TOP" in line and string_found:
            temp[line_num] = line.replace("\n", "")
            string_found = False

print(temp)
```

Comment: You may explain your solution, not just post code and leave

Comment: The dictionary temp contains any lines that contains "TOP". I want only the lines just coming after "IPT" lines.

Comment: @azro I've added comments, sorry about that.

Comment: @OmerT I've tested with your input file and it returns only lines with "TOP" after an "IPT" so I'm not sure what is messing it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = myfile.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):

...

    if line[12:17] == "IPT":
        temp[fileNum] = line.replace('\n', '')

        for j, line2 in enumerate(lines[i:]):
        if line2[12:15] == "TOP":
            print(line2)
            break
```

What it does is when it finds IPT line, it loops another one but slicing from the IPT line to next.

Comment: Read the whole question, he want to find all TOP where are just after a IPT line. Also a ode only answer is not valuable, and a "I post code then write text" is not a solution too ;)

Comment: @azro yep it finds all the top after ipt

Comment: Your code doesn't output what the OP expect , look better not all TOP should be found

Comment: @azro I don't want to find all "TOP" lines after an "IPT" line. Only and only the first "TOP" line after an "IPT" line.

Comment: @OmerT Look my answer below, that 100% what you expect ;)

Comment: yep, same output, i just did the `print`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {}
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    ipt_found = False
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        # For every line number and line in the file
        if 'IPT' in line:
            # If we find IPT in the line then we set ipt_found to True
            ipt_found = True
        elif 'TOP' in line and ipt_found:
            # If we find TOP in the line and ipt_found is True then we add the line
            result[index] = line
            # Set ipt_found to False so we don't append anymore lines with TOP in
            # until we find another line with IPT in
            ipt_found = False
print(result)
```